# How to speed up JqueryMobile + Phonegap app

Tags: iphone, jquery-mobile, cordova

I developed a iPhone App with JqueryMobile and Phoenagap. I minified all files with code, deleted unused files, but app is still quite slow. Problem is. If i tap on button transformation will started appdrox. after 1 second. I Would like to do pages transitions more quick.

I also disable unused part od device (Camera, etc,) but is it still slow.

Can anybody help me With this problem?

I testing on iPhone 4g.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### Pointers for improving performance

Cache jQuery Objects

```
Ex: var header = $('#header');
```

Consider alternatives to:

- jQuery.each()
- .show()
- .hide()
- .toggle()

Changing to `display:none` is much faster. Maybe just use `addClass('hidden')` and `removeClass('hidden')`

Minimize the use of slow jQuery methods
    O(n^2)

- remove()
- html()
- empty()

The following methods are expensive as well:

- append()
- prepend()
- before()
- after()

The process behind these manipulation methods is the following: cleaning the input string, converting the string into a DOM fragment and injecting it into the DOM.

Optimize selectors:

In order of performance:

- id (due to uniqueness)
- tag
- name, class (both require checking attributes of every DOM element)

Get specific, preferably choosing a parent's id to start with:

```
    $('#test p.description').removeClass('hidden');
    instead of 
    $('.description').removeClass('hidden');
```

Use the child selector where possible instead of descendant selector:

```
    $('div > p').hide(); or $('div').children('p'); 
    instead of
    $('div p').hide(); or $('div').find('p');
```

Use find over context:

```
    $('div').find('p');
    instead of
    $('div', 'p');
```

Use .filter() instead of using tag selectors:

```
    $('div.name').filter(':input');
    instead of
    $('div.name :input');
```

Memoization:

```
var myFunc = function (param) {
    if (!myFunc.cache.hasOwnProperty(param)) {
            var result = {};
            // ... expensive operation ...
            myFunc.cache[param] = result;
    }
    return myFunc.cache[param];
};

// cache storage
myFunc.cache = {};
```

Comment: What do you suggest as alternatives for `hmtl()` and `empty()`

Comment: I don't suggest any alternatives, just to minimize the usage of these slower functions.

Answer (score 7):

While Brett Holt's answer provides a lot of great tips for making your app more efficient, I think part of the problem with that delay you're speaking about has to do with the WebKit engine that's rendering your app. There is a built-in delay of *~300ms* before a click is registered, to allow for double-click events.

Based on my research, the concensus seems to be to bind to the '`vclick`' event rather than '`click`'. `vclick` should fire as soon as you tap on your object.

I use a library I've found called [jquery.touchToClick](https://github.com/cargomedia/jquery.touchToClick) in my app, which automatically handles converting `click` events over to `vclick`. This sped up my click events very noticeably. Keep in mind, though, that it might not be the most efficient way of going about solving this problem.

I've also seen alternative libraries to `jquery.touchToClick` out there, such as [LightningTouch](https://github.com/trott/LightningTouch), but I have not tried them.

Answer (score 0):

This has helped in my case, it reduces the hoverDelay and makes the UI more responsive on touchscreen devices.

```
$(document).on("mobileinit", function(){
    $.mobile.buttonMarkup.hoverDelay = 0;
});
```

You could also disable transitions, sadly this makes jQueryMobile fast.

```
$(document).on("mobileinit", function(){
    $.mobile.defaultPageTransition   = 'none';
    $.mobile.defaultDialogTransition = 'none';
});
```