# Speeding up iOS PhoneGap dom updates

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, backbone.js, cordova

I'm currently developing my first app using Backbone JS and I seem to have ran into a small performance issue.
I'm testing on my iPhone 5, accessing the app through my IP as it's on my localhost.

A little background behind what's going on:

The app is the classic game Hangman, and the issue arises when tapping a letter to guess and updating the word *if it's a correct guess*, which in turn updates the users score.

When there is a correct guess, the class is changed on the letter in the word in order to reveal it, the users score is then updated.
My view listens to changes in the models score, and when it detects a change, updates the score element in the DOM.

**The problem is the following:**

There seems to be a slight delay in changing the class on the guessed letter(s) in the word, when commenting out the line that updates the score however, **scoreEl.text(this.model.get('score'));** the letters are updated immediately as expected.

This issue obviously isn't present when testing in a desktop browser however does occur when testing in Chrome for iOS and slightly worse in Safari for iOS which is the browser that will be used as I intend to use PhoneGap/Cordova to deploy the game to the App Store.

I've followed the points [in the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10977510/how-to-speed-up-jquerymobile-phonegap-app) the best I can.

I hope I've made myself clear, if there's any questions feel free to ask.

Thanks!

Comment: try using fastclick to get rid of the mobile click delay: https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. Sorry I forgot to mention I am also using that which does get rid of the 300ms delay however this issue seems to be to do with updating the score element in the DOM as removing that fixes the issue.